Integrating $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ over part of circle
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

If $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ represents the population density of a planar region on the Earth, where $x$ and $y$ are measured in miles, find the number of people in the region shown below.


I can't find an answer for this. The place I am stuck is whether the integral should be like
$$\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}} \int_{3}^{5} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$
or not.

Hint: polar coordinates.

No, what you're currently integrating over is the rectangle $[5,3]\times\left[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right]$, but you want to integrate over $D=\left{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:r\in(3,5),,\theta\in\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)\right}$. To integrate to $D$, it thus makes sense to integrate in polar coordinates, as polar coordinates transform regions defined like this into rectangles, which you can easily integrate over. So the integral you want is $\iint_Df(x,y),\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y$, but you want to integrate it by changing to polar coordinates

@shgwani2804 the problem is not asking for the area of $D$. Notice that OP is given a density to integrate over $D$, which is the distance from the origin squared

When you integrate a function $f$ as
$$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
the region you're integrating over is the rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. The way you can see this is that you're essentially for each $x\in[a,b]$ sweeping out the line $\{x\}\times[c,d]$, and so by doing this for all $x\in[c,d]$, we get the aforementioned rectangle. In particular, as your region isn't rectangular, it cannot be an integral of this form. Instead you have the region
$$D=\left\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:3\leq r\leq 5,\,\frac{3\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\frac{5\pi}{4}\right\}.$$
Notice how if I expressed the region above in polar coordinates $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, then $(r,\theta)$ lies in a rectangle. Note, however, that this does not mean that $(x,y)$ lies in a rectangle, however we can use a change of variables into polar coordinates to get our integral in terms of $(r,\theta)$, and hence get a rectangular region. So our integral is
$$I=\iint_D f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\overset{\substack{\text{polar}\\\text{coordinates}}}{=}\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\int_3^5 f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
You should note the extra factor of $r$, which comes from the Jacobian of the change of variables. Now we simple note that
$$f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r^2,$$
so
$$I=\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\int_3^5 r^3\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
From here, I believe you can solve the problem yourself.
